# Beginner: JavaScript Tutorial - Cannot find the mistake here

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to learn JavaScript and Ajax with those tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpNx1W2UmHY&list=SP6gx4Cwl9DGDiJSXfsJTASx9eMq_HleHOnQ

However, I have to say that until now, even though I followed all the instructions, nothing seems to work out as shown. I did also read the code very carefully over and over.

Here is my JSfiddle for a small part of the tutorial. Just wanted to try wheter it even makes sense to continue watching.

```
<body onload="createList()">Here are my favourite movies:
  <br/>
  <div id="divMovies"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createList(){
    var s;
    s = "<ul>" + "<li>Armagetion</li>" + "<li>Position Impossible</li>" + "<li>Hallooo</li>" + "</ul>";

    divMovies = document.getElementById ("divMovies");
    divMovies.innerHTML = s;
}
```

**Fiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/7zfwT/1/

Would be nice if anyone could have a quick look here. I am not quite sure anymore whether this is the right way to start learning ajax.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't have the .js file in the <script>

Comment: Where is your JS code for sending asynchronous request ?

Comment: Ali Gajani it is the code copied from jsfiddle. There it says I dont need a header and a script-tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7zfwT/4/

Comment: dreamweiver this is just the part of the very beginning of the tutorial. Since not even this works like shown in the video I am asking myself whether I have a mistake in here and if I should continue with those tutorials..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't have Javascript function in fiddle.

Put following code in `Javascript` section:

```
function createList(){
    var s;
    s = "<ul>" + "<li>Armagetion</li>" + "<li>Position Impossible</li>" + "<li>Hallooo</li>" + "</ul>";

    divMovies = document.getElementById ("divMovies");
    divMovies.innerHTML = s;
}
```

Also, change the fiddle setting `No wrap in <body>` instead of **'onLoad'**.

**[Working Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/7zfwT/3)**

Comment: Thanks! So if I choose no wrap in jsfiddle I can still use the header in html and then the code I put in the bottom js box works?

Comment: what does "no wrap" mean exactly?

Comment: You can skip the JS part from HTML section or write the JS as written by 'Sachyn Kosare'. Since the reference '<script src="movies.js"></script>' doesn't mean anything here.

Comment: Link for "no wrap" mean: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions

Comment: Adding more info on this. 'Wrap' means Fiddle will internally wrap the JS you have written in JavaScript section based on 'onLoad' or 'onDomready' option. It is similar to writting <body onload="function(){ 'your JS code written in JS Fiddle JS Section' };">